# Automatic Conversion of contents in excel to word

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word, converters, data-conversion

I have the following table in an Excel file
Code, Description, and Value are table headers. C1, C2, and C2 are values of Code. Error, Code Change, and New code are values of Description.

| Code | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Error | ABC |
| C2 | Code Change | XYZ |
| C3 | New Code | AXBYC |

I wanted the above-mentioned Excel file contents to the following format in the word

```
Code: C1
Description: Error
Value: ABC


Code: C2
Description: Code Change
Value: XYZ


Code: C3
Description: New Code
Value: AXBYC
```

I wanted an automated way to do this.
Looking for suggestions and input.

I tried some simple Python scripts. But I did not get it in the required format.
Also, checked the Excel menu and could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Use Microsoft Word `Mail-Merge` method.